# Python Plot Drawing parallel diagonal lines using data, not axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw parallel diagonal lines. The second diagonal line should be 5% below the first one and the third one should be 5% above the first one. I do not want to use the axis limits because my data is not stationary, it is volatile. So, I want to use actual limits. My code works fine and produces the output. Whether this is the correct approach or not I have no idea. I mean, 5% below 1200 is 1200*0.95 but how to get 5% below at close to the origin. In my code, I have used 50 by trial and error.

My code and output:

```
plt.plot([0,1200],[50,1200*1.05],'k--',linewidth=2)
plt.plot([0,1200],[0,1200],'k--',linewidth=2)
plt.plot([50,1200],[0,1200*0.95],'k--',linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Comment: You can't recalculate every y value as a percentage as this will just change the gradient of the line. You need to ADD the same amount to EVERY y value (or minus) to shift it up or down while keeping the same gradient

Comment: @GhandiFloss Thanks a ton. Yes! I figured out that suppose 5% of 1000 is 50. I should use this number to the plot below and above lines. Your comment reassured me. THanks

Comment: `print(1200+(1200*(5/100)))` `print(1200-(1200*(5/100)))` for 5+% and 5-% .Hence consider x as your number i.e. 1200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw diagonal lines, regardless of the current *x* / *y* limits,
the most natural approach is to:

- specify ending poins of lines in **axes coordinates** (*0* to *1*),
- pass *transform=ax.transAxes*.

Running the following example code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(xlim=(0, 1250), ylim=(0, 1200))
ax.text(0.05, 0.95, 'Diagonal lines', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=12, va='top')
# Diagonal
plt.plot([0,    1],    [0,    1],    'k--', linewidth=1, transform=ax.transAxes)
# 5 % down
plt.plot([0.05, 1],    [0,    0.95], 'r--', linewidth=1, transform=ax.transAxes)
# 5 % up
plt.plot([0,    0.95], [0.05, 1],    'g--', linewidth=1, transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

I got the following plot:

[image]

I deliberately used different colors of lines, to ease their identification.

Experiment with this code, changing *xlim* and *ylim*, and each time
all 3 lines should be at just the same positions.